# PRISM: IDialogService trouble with implementing (xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, alert, prism

I am trying to make IDialogService in mvvm since i need to show alerts in viewmodel. But i am having hardtime getting IDialogService instance, every way i ended up getting error or null instance. I can't have it as parameter in ctor because i need parameterless ctor.

So my question is how to implement IDialogService?

here is my code:

Method that I call to show dialog window:

```
public void ShowAlert(string message, string title)
        {
            var parameters = new DialogParameters
            {
                { "title", title },
                { "message", message }
            };
            _dialogService.ShowDialog("DialogWindow", parameters);
        }
```

registering dialog service:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
...
containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<DialogWindow>("DialogWindow");
...
}
```

DialogWindow view:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             BackgroundColor="white"
             x:Class="Clients.DialogWindow">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <BoxView Color="Black"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
           Margin="20,10"
           TextColor="White"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Message}"
           Margin="20,0,20,10"
           Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button Text="Ok"
            Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Margin="10"
            WidthRequest="50"
            Grid.Row="2"/>

</Grid>
```

dialog window vm:

```
class DialogWindowViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
    {

        public DialogWindowViewModel()
        {
            CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => RequestClose(null));
        }
        public event Action<IDialogParameters> RequestClose;

        public DelegateCommand CloseCommand { get; }
        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get => title;
            set => SetProperty(ref title, value);
        }

        private string message;
        public string Message
        {
            get => message;
            set => SetProperty(ref message, value);
        }

        public bool CanCloseDialog() => true;


        public void OnDialogClosed()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
        {
            Message = parameters.GetValue<string>("message");
            Title = parameters.GetValue<string>("title");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: What version of Prism are you using.... what is null?

Comment: @DanSiegel i believe it is version 8
when i am trying to get instance of IDialogService so i can use commands that comes with it..  (_dialogService)

Comment: can you provide a sample that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can direct Inject the Dialog Service on the constructor.
You can have a parameterless constructor and other whit parameters.

I resolved this probleme by having 2 constructors

```
public IDialogService _dialogService;
    
public ConstructorViewModel(DialogService dialogService)
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;
}

public ConstructorViewModel()
{
 // Parameterless Constructor
}
```